# Pipe string to GNU Date for conversion - how to make it read from stdin?

Tags: linux, shell, date, pipe, stdin

GNU Date lets you convert date strings like so:

```
$ date +"%d %m %Y" -d "yesterday"
  04 01 2012
```

Is it possible to pipe a date string to it for conversion?  I've tried the obvious `-d -` like so:

```
$ echo "yesterday" | date +"%d %m %Y" -d -
```

but it prints today's date instead of yesterdays.

Is it possible to pipe values to it or doesn't it support that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the sudden downvote, 2 years after I asked this question?  I don't mind being downvoted, but an explanation as to why and as to how the question could be improved would be very much appreciated...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes.

```
 echo "yesterday" | xargs date +"%d %m %Y" -d
```

Comment: use `xargs  -0` to make it work with a date with spaces in it ;)

Answer (score 56):

date `-f` tells it to do the same thing as `-d` except for every line in a file... you can set the filename to `-` to make it read from standard input.

```sh
echo "yesterday" | date +"%d %m %Y" -f -
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `` `command` `` or `$(command)` substitution:

```
date +"%d %m %Y" -d $(echo "yesterday")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it in, in bash:

```
date +"%d %m %Y" -f <(echo yesterday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **stdin** as **file**:

```
command | date --file=-
```