# Piping to UNIX date function

Tags: unix, date

To format a date to timestamp, I'd use eg `date -d "2012-05-06 12:12" "+%s"`. But if I have a file with date per line how could I do something like:

```
cat file.txt | date "+%s" # does not work
```

I could do the following:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do `date -d "$line" "+%s"`; done;
```

but this is utterly ugly...

Other solution converting date-time to timestamp (in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) is acceptable as well.

Edit: My real life example is a bit more complex, let me elaborate:

```
`some command that produces complex lines` | grep only-speicif-lines | awk '{ print $5 | (I WANT TO PASS THE DATE HERE TO GET TIMESTAMP IN THE END)}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe string to GNU Date for conversion - how to make it read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742476/pipe-string-to-gnu-date-for-conversion-how-to-make-it-read-from-stdin)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This makes it:

```
while read mydate
do
  date -d "$mydate" "+%s"
done < file
```

Note that your solution

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do `date -d "$line" "+%s"`; done;
```

is not the way to read a file line per line. You need to

```
while read line; do `date -d "$line" "+%s"`; done < file.txt
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
2012-05-06 12:12
2012-05-06 12:13
$ while read mydate; do date -d "$mydate" "+%s"; done < a
1336299120
1336299180
```

---

## Update

From your comment:

> Edit: My real life example is a bit more complex, let me elaborate:
>
> ```
> `some command that produces complex lines` | grep only-speicif-lines | awk '{ print $5 | (I WANT TO PASS THE DATE HERE
> ```
>
> TO GET TIMESTAMP IN THE END)}'

This can make it:

```
xargs -i date -d "{}" "+%s"
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a | grep 2 | xargs -i date -d "{}" "+%s"  # grep here is just a silly example
1336299120
1336299180
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **stdin** as **file**:

```
command | date --file=-
```