# How do I extract log entries between two times without date?

Tags: bash

I am trying to have an automated script that can take the latest log entry and collect all the log entries from two hours back regardless of if there are log entries that exist during that time. The issue I keep running into for research is that all the examples I find have a date attached and I do not. A sample log output is:

```
13:26:28.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
13:26:28.713687 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9287:9522, ack 13044, win 420, length 235
13:26:28.713766 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364 > unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https: Flags [.], ack 9522, win 24576, length 0
13:26:28.840650 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364 > unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https: Flags [.], seq 14286:15624, ack 9522, win 24576, length 1338
13:26:28.848949 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9522:9599, ack 14286, win 420, length 77
13:26:28.849002 IP term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364 > unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https: Flags [P.], seq 15624:15674, ack 9599, win 24576, length 50
13:26:28.849023 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9599:9743, ack 14286, win 420, length 144
13:26:28.849031 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9743:10269, ack 14286, win 420, length 526
```

So my time is at the front with no date. And date does not like using this, giving me a `date: invalid date ‘+%s’` response and does not output anything.
My current work is:

```
#!/bin/bash

truncate -s 0 twoHour.log

NEW=$(tail -n1 $1 | cut -d ":" -f1)
# echo $NEW
New=$(date -d "$NEW" +%s)
OLD=$(($NEW-2))
New=$(date -d "$OLD" +%s)
# echo $OLD
START=$(egrep "$NEW\:\d\d\:\d\d" $1 | tail | date -d +%s)
END=$(egrep "$OLD\:\d\d\:\d\d" $1 | head | date -d +%s)

while read line; do

    # Extract the date for each line.
    # First strip off everything up to the first "[".
    # Then remove everything after the first "]".
    # Finally, straighten up the format with the cleandate function
    date="${date%%.*}"
    date=$( cleandate "$date" )

    # If the date falls between d1 and d2, print it
    if [[ $date -ge $START && $date -le $END ]]; then
         echo "$line"
    fi

done
```

NEW and OLD are for the hours that are getting extracted. START and END are the boundaries where everything between the two gets outputted line by line. The $1 is for a log file.

I have been trying to modify bash/awk scripts and searching for any premade ones for several hours now, so I am at a loss on how to get this to work.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output **for that** sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` can be used to extract lines expressed by regexp adresses
`/^11:.*$/,/^13:26:28.849031 .*$/p`

First address could be further refined by getting the minutes digits  and adding to the expression  as
`/^11:(2[6-9]|[3-5][0-9]).*$/,/^13:26:28.849031 .*$/p`

```
last_line=$(tail -n1 test.txt)
end_time=$(cut -d ' ' -f1 <<<"$last_line")
end_hour="${end_time:0:2}"
min_msb="${end_time:3:1}"
min_next=$(($min_msb+1))
min_lsb="${end_time:4:1}"
start_hour=$(($end_hour-2))

if [ "$min_msb" -lt 5 ];then
  min_next=$(($min_msb+1))
else
  min_next=5
fi

sed -rn "/^$start_hour:($min_msb[$min_lsb-9]|[$min_next-5][0-9]).*$/,/^$end_time .*$/p" test.txt
```

**If times span more than 24 h**

```
22:57:46.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
23:26:28.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
...
00:36:28.849031 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9743:10269, ack 14286, win 420, length 526
```

Then
**UPDATE**: fixed regexp for sed first address when time is across midnight.

```
hour_range=2
last_line=$(tail -n1 test.txt)
#end_time=$(cut -d ' ' -f1 <<<"$last_line")
end_time="${last_line:0:8}"

start_time="$(date -d "$(date -d "$end_time" --iso=seconds) -$hour_range hour" '+%T')"
echo "Time range: $start_time - $end_time"

end_hour="$(printf "%d" ${end_time:0:2})"
min_msb="$(printf "%d" ${end_time:3:1})"
min_lsb="$(printf "%d" ${end_time:4:1})"
start_hour="$(printf '%d' ${start_time:0:2})"

if [ "$min_msb" -lt 5 ];then
  min_next=$(($min_msb+1))
else
  min_next=5
fi
# Crossed midnight
start_hour_expr="$start_hour:($min_msb[$min_lsb-9]|[$min_next-5][0-9])"
if [ "$start_hour" -gt "$end_hour" ];then
  start_hour_lsb_next=$((${start_hour:1:1} + 1))
  start_hour_next="${start_hour:0:1}${start_hour_lsb_next}"
  if [ "$start_hour_next" -eq 24 ]; then
     start_hour_next="00"
  fi
  start_hour_expr="($start_hour_expr|$start_hour_next:[0-5][0-9])"
fi

echo "sed expression:"
echo -e "/^$start_hour_expr.*$/,/^$end_time.*$/p \n"

sed -rn "/^$start_hour_expr.*$/,/^$end_time.*$/p" test.txt
```

Given

```
21:32:28.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
21:57:46.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
22:10:46.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
23:07:46.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
23:26:28.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
00:26:28.849023 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9599:9743, ack 14286, win 420, length 144
00:36:28.849031 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9743:10269, ack 14286, win 420, length 526
```

Returns

```
sed expression:
/^(22:(3[6-9]|[4-5][0-9])|23:[0-5][0-9]).*$/,/^00:36:28.*$/p 

23:07:46.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
23:26:28.709883 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9136:9287, ack 13044, win 420, length 151
00:26:28.849023 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9599:9743, ack 14286, win 420, length 144
00:36:28.849031 IP unn-37-19-198-173.datapacket.com.https > term-IdeaPad-Flex.46364: Flags [P.], seq 9743:10269, ack 14286, win 420, length 526
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- the offset (2 hours in OP's example) is less than 24 hours
- **every** line starts with a timestamp of the format `HH:MM:SS`
- the log may span multiple days

Plan:

- convert offset (eg, `2 hrs`) to seconds; we'll call this `offset_secs`
- grab time from last line of file; we'll call this `last_time`
- convert the timestamp to epoch/seconds; we'll call this `last_epoch`
- subtract `offset_secs` from `last_epoch`; we'll call this `first_epoch`
- convert `first_epoch` back into a `HH:MM:SS` string; we'll call this `first_time`
- to address the file's timestamps spanning multiple midnights we'll save the lines of interest in an array, resetting the array when we find we have another midnight to go
- during `awk/END` processing we print our array of lines to stdout

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
$ cat log.awk
BEGIN { FS="." }                                # set input field delimiter to "."

# first line of input is last line of log file; grab time and calculate the offset/start time

NR==1 { last_time   = $1
        last_epoch  = mktime( strftime("%Y %m %d") " " gensub(/:/," ","g",last_time))
        first_epoch = last_epoch - offset_secs
        first_time  = strftime("%H:%M:%S", first_epoch)

        if (first_time > last_time)
           spans_midnight=1
        next
      }

# for the rest of the input lines determine if the time falls within the last "offset_secs"

      { curr_time = $1
        if ( (  spans_midnight && curr_time >= first_time) ||
             (  spans_midnight && curr_time <= last_time)  ||
             ( !spans_midnight && curr_time >= first_time && curr_time <= last_time) )
           lines[++cnt]=$0
        else {                                  # outside the time range so ...
           delete lines                         # delete anything saved up to this point and ...
           cnt=0                                # reset the array index
        }
      }
END   { for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++)                    # print the lines that occurred within the last "offset_secs"
            print lines[i]
      }
```

**NOTE:** see [GNU awk: Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for more details on the `mktime()` and `strftime()` functions

**Test #1:** last 2 hours; does not span midnight; file spans midnight

```
$ cat sample.log
22:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
06:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line; crossed midnight
07:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
09:23:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
09:51:49.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
09:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
10:24:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
11:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line

$ offset_secs=$((2*60*60))                   # 2 hours

$ awk -v offset_secs="${offset_secs}" -f log.awk <(tail -1 sample.log) sample.log
09:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
10:24:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
11:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
```

**Test #2:** last 4 hours; spans midnight; file spans multiple midnights

```
$ cat sample.log
20:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
23:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
01:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line; crossed midnight
23:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
01:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line; crossed midnight
06:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
07:22:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
09:23:00.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
22:51:49.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  ignore this line
22:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
23:07:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
00:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line; crossed midnight
01:24:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
02:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line

$ offset_secs=$((4*60*60))                   # 4 hours

$ awk -v offset_secs="${offset_secs}" -f log.awk <(tail -1 sample.log) sample.log
22:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
23:07:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
00:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line; crossed midnight
01:24:37.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
02:51:50.896232 IP 104.16.42.63.https  keep this line
```

Answer (score 0):

`egrep` is limited in it's regular expression capabilities. You can use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`, but not `\d`. If you want `\d`, you can use the Perl style RegEx with `grep -P`.

You can also tell `grep` to only output matching data with `-o`

It's worth noting that `egrep` and `grep -E` are synonymous; I recommend being explicit and using `grep -E`, but that's just my preference.

```
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

For `tail` and `head`, it looks like you're looking for a single, first and last, line for each. By default, they output 10 lines. This can be controlled with `-n 1`

Your date command is failing because it doesn't know which file to read from. You can specify `-f -` to indicate the input file is STDIN ([Pipe string to GNU Date for conversion - how to make it read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742476/pipe-string-to-gnu-date-for-conversion-how-to-make-it-read-from-stdin))

With that, the following should get you on your way.

```
START=$(egrep -o "$NEW:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+" $1 | tail -n 1 | date +%s -f -)
END=$(egrep -o "$OLD:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+" $1 | head -n 1| date +%s -f -)
```

Hint: Use `bash -x` when troubleshooting bash scripts to get a better idea of what's going on.

```
[root@91192da89fc4 temp]# bash -x date-orig.sh log
+ truncate -s 0 twoHour.log
++ tail -n1 log
++ cut -d : -f1
+ NEW=13
++ date -d 13 +%s
+ New=1651582800
+ OLD=11
++ date -d 11 +%s
+ New=1651575600
++ egrep '13\:\d\d\:\d\d' log
++ tail
++ date -d +%s
date: invalid date '+%s'
+ START=
++ egrep '11\:\d\d\:\d\d' log
++ head
++ date -d +%s
date: invalid date '+%s'
+ END=
+ read line
```